# IntegrityError "django_session_pkey"

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm contributing to a django application which from time to time crashes responding with:

```
IntegrityError at /signin/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_session_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (session_key)=(ahwvmdwpz5hg1rnu8q7ctudvfl9nfnga) already exists.
```

To me it makes absolutely no sense, as session key is always randomly generated and it is almost impossible to see this kind of error. When it happens it blocks the whole site, as users get this for every request, no matter what browser or system. The only way to get rid of this is to reboot machine.

Has anyone ever seen this error or has any permanent solution? 
I tried to google it, but found no sensible results.

Comment: Go buy a lottery ticket mate!

Comment: I have seen this twice in the span of about a year with one of the django (1.6.x) sites i maintain. i don't get it either. there is no need to restart anything after it happens, the app works normally. the session key mentioned in the stacktrace does not exist in the session table after it happens. i am assuming it's because it was created in a transaction, that was later reverted due to the exception. at some point in the stracktrace django decides to make an insert instead of an update. my guess there is the root cause.

Comment: Might be related to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16484

Comment: seen it 13 times within a year with djang 1.9.9

Comment: I just got this error with a Flask app! Not Django-specific, clearly.

Comment: @ZachSiegel Why do you have a django sessions table in your flask app?

Comment: @DylanYoung I do not recall, but I’m sure I had an ‘IntegrityError’ involving a duplicate ‘session_id’. I don’t think my comment was relevant.